# Erro with firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm new in flutter.
Im tried to connect with firebase to do a validation email and password in a screen login.

**Code:**

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:login/page.dart';
import 'package:login/register_page.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

import 'forgivePassword.dart';

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  String _email, _password;
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      body: Center(
        child: SizedBox(
          width: 380,
          height: 400,
          child: Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: Card(
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)
              ),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(50.0, 1.0, 50.0, 1.0),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      validator: (input){
                        if(input.isEmpty){
                          return ;
                        }
                      },
                      onSaved: (input) => _email = input,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: "E-mail",
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0))
                        )
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),

                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(50.0, 1.0, 50.0, 0.0),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      validator: (input){
                        if(input.length < 6){
                          return 'Your password needs to be atleast 6 characters';
                        }
                      },
                      onSaved: (input) => _password = input,
                      obscureText: true,
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          labelText: "Password",
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)))),
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(178, 0, 0, 0),
                        child: TextButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                                          ForgivePassword()));
                            },
                            child: Text(
                              "Esqueci minha senha",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.blue,
                                decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                              ),
                            )),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                      width: 310,
                      height: 35,
                      child: RaisedButton(
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        textColor: Colors.white,
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                        ),
                        onPressed: sigIn,
                        child: Text("Login"),
                      )),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0),
                    child: SizedBox(
                        width: 310,
                        height: 35,
                        child: RaisedButton(
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          textColor: Colors.white,
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                                        PaginaRegistro()));
                          },
                          child: Text("Registre-se"),
                        )),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  Future<void> sigIn() async{
    final formState = _formKey.currentState;
    if(formState.validate()){
      try{
        UserCredential user =  await FirebaseAuth.
        instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: _email, password: _password);
        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Home()));
      }catch(e){
        print(e.massage);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Err:**

> Performing hot restart... Syncing files to device AOSP on IA
> Emulator... Restarted application in 925ms. E/flutter ( 4428):
> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception:
> NoSuchMethodError: Class 'FirebaseException' has no instance getter
> 'massage'. E/flutter ( 4428): Receiver: Instance of
> 'FirebaseException' E/flutter ( 4428): Tried calling: massage
> E/flutter ( 4428): #0      Object.noSuchMethod
> (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:54:5) E/flutter ( 4428): #1
> _MyAppState.sigIn (package:login/login_page.dart:149:17) E/flutter ( 4428): #2      _InkResponseState._handleTap
> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:991:20) E/flutter ( 4428):
> #3      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:182:24) E/flutter (
> 4428): #4      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp
> (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:598:11) E/flutter ( 4428): #5
> BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp
> (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:287:5) E/flutter ( 4428): #6
> BaseTapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer
> (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:222:7) E/flutter ( 4428): #7
> PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent
> (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:475:9) E/flutter (
> 4428): #8      PointerRouter._dispatch
> (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:93:12) E/flutter (
> 4428): #9      PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes. (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:138:9)
> E/flutter ( 4428): #10     _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach
> (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:397:8) E/flutter ( 4428): #11
> PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes
> (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:136:18) E/flutter (
> 4428): #12     PointerRouter.route
> (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:122:7) E/flutter (
> 4428): #13     GestureBinding.handleEvent
> (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:381:19) E/flutter ( 4428):
> #14     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:361:22) E/flutter ( 4428):
> #15     RendererBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:278:11) E/flutter ( 4428):
> #16     GestureBinding._handlePointerEventImmediately (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:316:7) E/flutter ( 4428):
> #17     GestureBinding.handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:280:5) E/flutter ( 4428):
> #18     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:238:7) E/flutter ( 4428):
> #19     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:221:7) E/flutter ( 4428):
> #20     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1202:13) E/flutter ( 4428): #21     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1097:19)
> E/flutter ( 4428): #22     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded
> (dart:async/zone.dart:1002:7) E/flutter ( 4428): #23     _invoke1
> (dart:ui/hooks.dart:176:10) E/flutter ( 4428): #24
> PlatformDispatcher._dispatchPointerDataPacket
> (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:276:7) E/flutter ( 4428): #25
> _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:96:31) E/flutter ( 4428):

Comment: Typo: ` print(e.massage);` should be ` print(e.message);` (with an `e` after the `m`).

Answer (score 0):

You've made a typing mistake. Use "print(e.m**e**ssage);" instead of "print(e.m**a**ssage);" in your print statement:

```
catch(e){
        print(e.message);
      }
```